# How to Shim private variable?

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

Is there a way to shim a private variable?

The library I'm testing uses a class level private variable, which I'd like to shim.

Comment: As far as I know, shims only apply to methods, and even then only ones  that are accessible. Generally speaking, if you need shims to access something, it can probably be designed better. If shims *can't* even access it, that likelihood increases tenfold.

Comment: Did you find your answer?